# Battery doesn't last long on Linux for Samsung series 9

Tags: kernel, power-management, battery

I recently purchased a [Samsung NP900X3N](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/windows-laptops/12-14/notebook-9-13-3---8gb-ram--np900x3n-k01us/) which came with Windows 10 installed. I used it for a while on Windows 10 and I noticed the battery lasted for a long time (I forgot to time it, but I felt like it lasted for as a long as it should have lasted for a new laptop with SSD and a 7th gen i5).

However, after I installed Linux Mint and upgraded to version 4.10 of the kernel (which was necessary for some cards to work) I feel like the battery doesn't last as long. If I watch a movie unplugged it lasts for less than 2 hours.

I get that from my old computer, which has an HDD and 5 year-old hardware, but I figured it should last longer with this laptop. (Although I do not have benchmarks for that to compare against.) Keep in mind that both my old computer and this new one have almost the same battery power (4400 mAh for the old and 4000 mAh for the new one).

My question is: is this behavior normal? Can it be related to the kernel? Is there something I can do to prolong the battery life? (I already keep the bluetooth turned off, but maybe there are other services that I don't use that are generally a good idea to leave off for battery-saving.)

Cheers

**EDIT**

I'm trying to first try things without installing TLP. If I can't really make a difference then I'll try TLP.

Comment: Try powertop (install the Mint package and run it).

Comment: @Gilles pretty cool program. I didn't know it. Helped, but didn't really give me that much of an increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `powertop` is a good alternative, but the fact that I have to re-do everything manually every time I turn on the computer kind of kills it for me. This made me have to install `tlp`, for which I found no alternative.

Comment: Once you run powertop, the idea is to set up services that manage those settings for every boot...

Comment: @jasonwryan that approach wasn't clear to me, but that is what I did. The only one I found was `tlp`.

Comment: TLP is a mess; you can write service files for any of the powertop tunings.

Comment: @jasonwryan I'd never heard that criticism about `tlp`, nor was I aware of writing service files. Care to post an answer or give me some reference I can read into?

Comment: No, that is a separate topic.